# how to copy and rename files with ":" and incrementing number in the filename

Tags: rename, filenames

I need to copy and rename (and then edit) a group of files in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` folder. The files are `ifcfg-eth1:*`

I have `ifcfg-eth1` through `ifcfg-eth1:121` but need to extend with more addresses, so I want to copy e.g `ifcfg-eth1:22` and `ifcfg-eth1:23` into `ifcfg-eth1:122` and `ifcfg-eth1:123` and then edit the copy.

I know how to edit, but not how to copy and rename. Found a lot of renaming info on this site, but I think I don't get the : part right...

How do I handle filenames including ":" ??

Comment: There's nothing special about `:` in a filename (except that Windows FAT filesystem doesn't allow that character)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question right, but in Bash this could work:

```
for n in {22..99} ; do cp "ifcfg-eth1:$n" "ifcfg-eth1:1$n"; done
```

That would copy `ifcfg-eth1:22` through `ifcfg-eth1:99` to `ifcfg-eth1:122` through `ifcfg-eth1:199`.

I'm not sure why you would use such files. If this is about ethX:Y aliases, you no longer need them. You can just `ip addr add` to the main interface. So maybe you should take a step back and ask a question about the problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! And I will consider your recommendation about "ip addr add"

Comment: Thanks for the tip as well regarding the `ip addr add` I wasn't aware of this change either.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as `mv "ifcfg-eth1:xx" "ifcfg-eth1:yy"`